# Why is mypy determining a parameter is optional?

Tags: python, mypy

I have inherited the following code

```py
import json
from flask import Request, jsonify



def main(request: Request = None):
    request_body = {}
    if request.is_json:
        request_body = request.get_json()
    elif request.mimetype == "application/octet-stream":
        try:
            request_body = json.loads(request.data.decode("utf8"))
        except Exception:
            pass

    # do some other work with request_body...
    #...
    return jsonify(message="DONE")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I'm now running mypy upon it (which I'm currently trying to educate myself about) and it is returning these errors:

```
google/runtime/modules/RealTimeIngestion/cloudFunctions/translate-schema/translate-schema/main.py:8: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Request]" has no attribute "is_json"
google/runtime/modules/RealTimeIngestion/cloudFunctions/translate-schema/translate-schema/main.py:9: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Request]" has no attribute "get_json"
google/runtime/modules/RealTimeIngestion/cloudFunctions/translate-schema/translate-schema/main.py:9: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Optional[Any]", variable has type "Dict[Any, Any]")
google/runtime/modules/RealTimeIngestion/cloudFunctions/translate-schema/translate-schema/main.py:10: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Request]" has no attribute "mimetype"
google/runtime/modules/RealTimeIngestion/cloudFunctions/translate-schema/translate-schema/main.py:12: error: Item "None" of "Optional[Request]" has no attribute "data"
```

I don't understand why argument `request: Request` is being interpreted as Optional. I did wonder if it was perhaps because of

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

however I commented that out and mypy still returned the same errors.

Why is mypy raising these errors?

Comment: you've given request the default value `None` in `request: Request = None`. if the default is `None` then it's an optional parameter.

Comment: `request` is initialized with `None`, so it is automatically handled as optional.  That `main` won't work as is, so I would just remove both `main` and the initialization with `None`.

Comment: thx folks. Couldn't see the wood for the trees

Answer (score 0):

- **Optional**:
  once we assign the default value to a parameter it become optional also [python_function_default_parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_function_default_parameter.asp)
- **Error**: you are getting error as Request is expected to have valid value and its throwing error when it tries to convert None to type Request